# OpenGL Auxiliary buffers

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm working on a project using OpenGL, C++ and Windows, I've been debugging with AMDs CodeXL and noticed that there's 4 full resolution "Auxiliary Buffers" alongside my front, back, depth and stencil buffers. As far as I can tell these are totally unused and are just taking up memory, I just wondered if there's any way to not initialize them, or perhaps this is more CodeXL erroneously reporting they are initialized?

As far as I can tell, the most I know about this code side is PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR which has flags for auxiliary and accumulation buffers, both of which are set to zero.

I just wondered if anybody else has experienced this and if it's avoidable at all (perhaps these buffers are required).

Thanks

**Update:**

Tried out the "proper" context creation link, which is better since it's explicit in its version conformity, however it did not resolve this issue. I ended up trying a for loop passing the counter as an index to DescribePixelFormat() try to match a format with 0 aux buffers and the rest of what I need, I basically couldn't find anything that supported it all and worked, here's the code for that search (just a basic test).

```
        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR targetPixFmt;

        memset(&targetPixFmt, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
        targetPixFmt.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
        targetPixFmt.nVersion = 1;
        targetPixFmt.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
        targetPixFmt.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
        targetPixFmt.cColorBits = colorBitDepth;
        targetPixFmt.cDepthBits = depthBitDepth;
        targetPixFmt.cStencilBits = stencilBitDepth;

        s32 pixFmtCounter = 1; // Starting at zero fails immediately ?

        for (;;)
        {
            PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR tempPixFmt;

            if (0 == DescribePixelFormat(m_deviceContext, pixFmtCounter,
                sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), &tempPixFmt))
                break;

            if ((tempPixFmt.dwFlags & targetPixFmt.dwFlags) == targetPixFmt.dwFlags &&
                targetPixFmt.iPixelType == tempPixFmt.iPixelType && 
                targetPixFmt.cColorBits <= tempPixFmt.cColorBits &&
                targetPixFmt.cDepthBits <= tempPixFmt.cDepthBits &&
                tempPixFmt.cAuxBuffers <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            pixFmtCounter++;
        }
```

I'm even being loose with the color and depth bits to try and get more results, the search finds two formats, both of which have a dwFlags set to 33893 which is **(PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_GENERIC_FORMAT | PFD_SWAP_COPY | PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION).**

If I use this format my first call to an OpenGL function fails because it is NULL and the pixel format is definitely the only change between failing and not.

I guess that's just the way it is?

Comment: Request a 3.2+ core profile, where the auxiliary buffers are gone, and hope the driver doesn't allocate them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using Glew to handle the wrangling of all things OpenGL, what's the best way to request a specific profile? What's weird is that if I request 0 bits for a stencil buffer in PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR it doesn't create a stencil and when I request 8 bits it creates a stencil buffer, but the same doesn't seem to apply to the aux buffers.

Comment: GLEW doesn't do context creation or management; all it does is load the OpenGL functions. How do you create your context/window?

Comment: It's essentially the same process as the Nehe tutorials for Windows (http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_(win32)/13001/)

- CreateWindowEx()
- ChoosePixelFormat()
- SetPixelFormat()
- wglCreateContext()
- wglMakeCurrent()

Perhaps this is just outdated and there's better ways to do it, or perhaps there's a flag I'm missing, I know in android you can specify what version of OpenGL ES you want, but didn't see anything like that for Windows.

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)#Proper_Context_Creation - Looks like it's a more up to date, will try.

Comment: Updated question with recent findings.